# python map object methods

Tags: python

I am looping through an array of objects, calling a method on each like so:

```
for cell in cells:
    cell.update_type(next_cells[cell.index])
```

Is there a way to do the equivalent with map()?

Comment: The loop is fine as it is.  Don't use `map()` or a list comprehension -- they are meant for cases you are interested in the list of return values of the function calls.

Comment: That's an important distinction, too. Suppose `len(cells) == 1000000000`. If you replace this loop with a `map()` or list comprehension, you'd be creating and managing a `list` with a billion entries and then throwing it away immediately afterward.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It appears `update_type` returns `None`, so you could use:

```
any(cell.update_type(next_cells[cell.index]) for cell in cells)
```

but unless there is a *problem* with a normal loop, just stick with that. It's the most readable and you shouldn't optimize prematurely.

You *shouldn't* use `map` here because there is no way to avoid using it on a Python function / lambda expression, so you won't get a speed advantage over a normal loop.

You *shouldn't* use a list comprehension because you're needlessly accumulating a list of the return values of `update_type` even though you're ignoring them -- use `any` instead.

Comment: thanks.  this makes sense.  the loop is running on something like a million cells so wanted to speed things up a little! never mind!

Comment: @agf: If `next_cells` is a Python list, an explicit call to `list.__getitem__` will slow things down instead of speeding them up.  Time it yourself if you don't belive me. :)

Comment: @SvenMarnach Interesting. That makes sense for something that would be optimized, but I'd never thought about it before. Removing that section (which was added as an afterthought, anyway).

Comment: @Ferguzz `any` might be faster than the normal loop. Also make sure all variable lookups are local.

Comment: -1 because you're doing micro optimizations, without any reason to optimize at all. The result is that a perfectly fine loop was turned into something less readable and more fragile. The only good advice in this answer is to stick with the for loop.

Comment: @JochenRitzel "but unless there is a problem with a normal loop, just stick with that. It's the most readable and you shouldn't optimize prematurely." is the direct instruction in the post. How much more clear could I be, while still providing an alternate method?

Comment: @Jochen: Please reconsider the downvote.  This answer *is* helpful, and the OP explicitly states that the whole purpose of his question was micro-optimization (see the first comment to this answer).

Comment: the any() does speed things up very slightly. another interesting note is that using `for i, cell in enumerate(cells)` instead of `cell.index` also shaves off a few ms when used with any() but doesn't have any effect when used in the normal for loop.